# how to hide revision number from eclipse explorer view?

Tags: eclipse, svn, revision, subversive

[image]

Is there any way to hide this number as this number has gone too long ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can remove the label decorations from the `Team->SVN->Label Decorations` preferences page. See [this page](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/preferences/pref_label_decors.php) for details.

Comment: after doing the need full changes I had to restart eclipse to see those number gone . Thanks

Comment: I found I could just refresh the Project Explorer to have the changes take effect.

Comment: wow, even found out how to get back the last updated date after reinstalling!

Comment: My machine was not showing version labels, and I followed your instructions. It worked for me. +1

Answer (score 16):

In Eclipse Kepler go Window -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Label Decorations -> and uncheck SVN.

However, note that this will also turn off all of the other indicators such as the ">" or "<" sign, which indicates changes to the repository as compared to the checked-out version... at least, this is true in Eclipse Kepler.

Comment: My machine was not showing version labels, and I followed your instructions. It worked for me. +1